# Best way to layout images in a list using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to layout a list of images using css into a grid as below:

[image: What I'm trying to acheieve]

The HTML code I have for the list is:

```
<ul id='feat-products'>
    <li><img id='feat-product-1'></li>
    <li><img id='feat-product-2'></li>
    <li><img id='feat-product-3'></li>
    <li><img id='feat-product-banner'></li>
</ul>
```

And my CSS is:

```
#feat-products ul {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
}    
#feat-products li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px;
}
#feat-products li:nth-child(1) {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
}
#feat-products li:nth-child(2) {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
}
#feat-products li:nth-child(3) {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
}
#feat-products li:nth-child(4) {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Unfortunately this is what I am getting from the code:

[image: Layout my code is giving me]

What is the best way to lay this out using CSS? I have been able to mess around and almost achieve what I want using negative margins, but can't imagine this is good practice. Would appreciate any assistance!

Thanks,

DB

Comment: Can you change `HTML` structure?

Comment: are you using fixed width and height for the ul and images(like your style) or they may be change later ?

Comment: @NenadVracar I'd prefer to keep the structure as a list, but open to other suggeststions.

Comment: @AhmedSalama I will be using a fixed width for the images, although I will use media queries to change accordingly for mobile/tablet design

Comment: @DingoBruce so why you don't use the absolute positions to layout them?

Comment: @AhmedSalama I'm not familiar working with absolute positioning. Could you give an example please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

edit your css like this add float left to li child 1

```
#feat-products ul {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
}    
#feat-products li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px;
}
#feat-products li:nth-child(1) {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
  float:left; //add this to your css
}
#feat-products li:nth-child(2) {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
}
#feat-products li:nth-child(3) {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
}
#feat-products li:nth-child(4) {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}
```